# Java comunicación con puertos seriales

Tags: java

como están? Queria ver si alguien puede darme una mano con un problema que estoy teniendo.

Quiero crear un programa de pesada con una bascula conectada por un puerto serial RS232.
Tengo la clase principal creada y no reconoce los puertos COM que tengo abiertos ( Emulados por virtual serial port ).

Dejo el codigo

Al ejecutarlo, no entra en el ciclo WHILE.

Agradecería su ayuda.
Muchas gracias!

```
import gnu.io.*;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class Pesaje2 {
    CommPortIdentifier port;
    static Enumeration portList;
    static SerialPort serialPort;
    static CommPortIdentifier portId;
    public void port(){
   portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();
      while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {
        portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
          System.out.println(portId);
}
    }
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Pesaje2 ini = new Pesaje2();
        ini.port();
    }
}
```

Comment: Estas usando RXTX?

Comment: Si, estoy usando RXTX